# OctoberCMS backend list with filter more than 500 records is not working

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

In my project I have a "products" model. Products model is related with another model called "brand". In "products" listing page I need to filter records depending upon a "brand". I have fetched all the brands from "brand" model and listed them in the filter.

```
# ===================================
# Filter Scope Definitions
# ===================================
scopes:

    brand:
        label: Brand
        modelClass: October\Demo\Models\Brand
        nameFrom: name
        scope: FilterBrands
```

If I have the brands **lesser than or equal to 500 records in DB**, the listing filter in product model **is working** good. But if I have the **records more than 500** it is **not working**.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to set a maximum value for "max_input_vars" but it doesn't work. I found a temporary solution for this issue, so, we have to modify the line $query->limit(500) in Filter.php file and voila. The problem is going to be when we update the October version that these changes are lost so we should keep that in mind ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Set/Update the maximum input value for "**max_input_vars**" attribute in **php.ini** file

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Or else you may add maximum input value in **htaccess** file as **php_value max_input_vars 10000**